# Visualizing helium’s interacting electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, computational-physics, simulations

I want to numerically simulate the experimental results seen in this [Phys. Rev. Lett.](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.113.103002) paper, specifically the interference patterns of ionized helium. The authors used photoionization microscopy to visualize interference narrowing in helium atoms, and hence explicitly reveal the mechanism by which Stark states decay.

Here is a higher resolution figure with more [background details](https://physicsworld.com/a/visualizing-heliums-interacting-electrons/):

[image]

Is there any existing Python or Matlab code that can numerically simulate these results? This paper was published in 2014 and I'm keen to see if anyone has written code since then to reproduce these figures (and therefore the physics behind them).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the logic of "reproducing figures for verification purposes" by using existing code. Wouldn't you have to write your own code based on the equations in the paper to actually verify the figures?

Comment: I clarified my question